# select cases where rows do not match

Tags: r

I want to identify rows where the id and visit do not match across person. Here is an example of my data:

```
id   visit
1      2
1      2
1      2
2      4
2      3
2      4
```

I want subject 2 to be identified as their visits do not match. How can I do this in R?

Comment: What is the expected output?? So `id` 2 is identified because there is not an unique visit for him?

Comment: @Duck, that's correct. I want those id's printed or in a df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can group by 'id' and `filter` those groups where the number of distinct elements in 'visit' is greater than 1

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   filter(n_distinct(visit)> 1) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   distinct(id)
# A tibble: 1 x 1
#     id
#  <int>
#1     2
```

---

Or using `table` from `base R` to find the 'id' having more than one unique element of 'visit'

```
names(which(rowSums(table(df1) > 0) > 1))
[1] "2"
```

Or take the `unique` and then do the `table`

```
names(which(table(unique(df1)$id) > 1))
#[1] "2"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), visit = c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d2 = aggregate(visit~id, d, function(x) length(unique(x)) > 1)
d2
#id visit
#1  1 FALSE
#2  2  TRUE

d2$id[d2$visit]
#[1] 2


# Data
d = structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
                   visit = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 4L)),
              class = "data.frame",
              row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```